# Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, count, report

I am trying to do a count based on certain criteria and I cannot get the criteria correct.

- Exclude Account Types: (8) non-member bond redemption; (15) estate restricted; (16) estate unrestricted and (17) dealer direct.
- Exclude Accounts with a Warning code 50 and Share ID 01s that have been closed 90 days or more
- Exclude deceased
- Exclude duplicate social security numbers

This is my query:

```
;with records as
(
select AD.AccountNumber AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       SD.ShareType AS TYPE,
       SD.SharePrimeNameSSN AS SSN,
       AD.AccountPrimeLongName AS NAME,
       SD.PROCESSDATE AS DATE,
row_number() over (partition by SD.sharePrimeNameSSN
order by SD.SHARETYPE ASC) N      
from arcu.ARCUAccountDetailed AD
join arcu.ARCUShareDetailed SD
on AD.accountnumber = sd.accountnumber AND
AD.ProcessDate = SD.ProcessDate
where 
AD.AccountPrimeNameDeathDate IS NULL AND
AD.AccountStatus = 'OPEN' AND
SD.ShareStatus = 'OPEN' AND
(SD.ShareType != '8' AND SD.ShareType != '15' AND SD.ShareType != '16'
AND SD.ShareType != '17') AND
(((AccountWarningcode1  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode2  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode3  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode4  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode5  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode6  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode7  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode8  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode9  != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode10 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode11 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode12 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode13 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode14 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode15 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode16 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode17 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode18 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode19 != '50' AND
AccountWarningcode20 != '50') AND 
(ShareID = 001 AND ShareCloseDate >= (GetDate() - 90)))
AND
AccountPrimeNameDeathDate is null
))
select Count(*) from records
where N = 1
```

I am receiving the following error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5.00' to data type int.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your ShareID is not a numeric field and the error comes from this:

```
ShareID = 001
```

You probably want

```
ShareID = '001'
```